# Magento 2 : How to Copy whole admin panel in custom route

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, routing

I want to create the whole admin panel in my custom route, like
here is the default method is `192.168.1.57/magento/admin` to 
`192.168.1.57/magento/demoroute` with all the functionalities of admin.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this CLI command:

`php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="demoroute"`

Comment: can u please explain this

Answer (score 0):

Please use this CLI command:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="demoroute"
```

Or You can change it from `app/etc/env.php`

```
'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admim',
  ),
```

to

```
'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'demoroute',
  ),
```

Once you change admin route '**admin**' to demoroute, all admin pages open by **demoroute** insteated of **admin**.

Comment: no i dont want this, in this admin route will be replace by `demoroute` but i dont want replace i want a clone of admin panel with 'demoroute'